# Getting QProcess::state() to a QString for some operations

Tags: qt, qt4

I want to get the QProcess state and if it the state() returns "Running" then I want to do few operations but if I do like this

```
QProcess myprocess;
QString mystring = myprocess.state()
if(mystring=="Running")
 {
//*My code
 }
else
 {
//*Other code
 }
```

But actually this gives me error as `error: conversion from 'QProcess::ProcessState' to non-scalar type 'QString' requested`

I know I am doing this in a wrong way. Can anyway point me to correct way?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
QProcess myprocess;

if(myprocess.state()==QProcess::Running)
 {
//*My code
 }
else
 {
//*Other code
 }
```

myprocess.state() returns [enum QProcess::ProcessState](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html#ProcessState-enum)